# Execute javascript Ajax and non-ajax calls in correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, notifications

I have a for loop that executes a function. This function, depending on a variable, executes an ajax request, or just appends to the HTML.

The code looks like this:

```
 var index = 0;
 for (index = 0; index < currentAmountOfUnreadNotifications; ++index) {
       var currNotification = response.notifications[index];
       createAndAppendNotification(notificationHtmlElement, baseUrl, localBaseUrl, currNotification);
 }

function createAndAppendNotification(ele, baseUrl, localBaseUrl, notification) {
    var notificationId = notification.notification_id;
    var subjectLangKey = notification.subject_js_lang_key;
    var messageLangKey = notification.message_js_lang_key;
    var urlLangKey = notification.cta_url_js_lang_key;
    var urlTranslation = res[urlLangKey];
    if (localBaseUrl) {
        var fullCtaUrl = localBaseUrl + "/" + urlTranslation;
    } else {
        var fullCtaUrl = baseUrl + "/" + urlTranslation;
    }
    var fromUserId = notification.from_user_id;
    var fromUserAuthLevel = notification.from_user_auth_level;
    var currLang = $('html').attr('lang');
    moment.locale(currLang);
    var timeSince = moment.utc(notification.timestamp_inserted_utc).fromNow();

    //If the from_user_id is filled in, we need to perform an additional AJAX request in order to retrieve the username and the profile picture/logo.
    if (fromUserId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            url: baseUrl + '/notification/ajaxmethods/getUserInfoForNotification',
            data: {
                'user_id': fromUserId,
                'auth_level': fromUserAuthLevel
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                var subjectTranslation = res[subjectLangKey].format(response.name);
                var messageTranslation = res[messageLangKey].format(response.name);

                var notificationHtml = '<a class="notification-cta" href="'+fullCtaUrl+'" data-notification-id="'+notificationId+'"><div class="media single-notification"><div class="media-left align-self-center"><span class="avatar avatar-online"><img src="'+response.picture+'" alt="avatar"></span></div><div class="media-body"><h6 class="media-heading yellow darken-3">'+subjectTranslation+'</h6><p class="notification-text font-small-3 text-muted">'+messageTranslation+'</p><small class="float-left"><time class="media-meta text-muted">'+timeSince+'</time></small><small class="float-right"><span class="media-meta cursor-pointer blue text-muted notification-mark-read" data-notification-id="'+notificationId+'">'+res.MarkAsRead+'</span></small></div></div></a>';

                ele.append(notificationHtml);
            }
        });
    } else {
        var subjectTranslation = res[subjectLangKey];
        var messageTranslation = res[messageLangKey];
        var iconClass;
        switch(notification.type) {
            case '0':
                iconClass = "ft-info";
                break;
            case '1':
                iconClass = "ft-check-circle";
                break;
            case '2':
                iconClass = "ft-info";
                break;
            case '3':
                iconClass = "ft-alert-triangle";
                break;
            case '4':
                iconClass = "ft-x-circle";
                break;
            default:
                iconClass = "";
            // code block
        }
        var notificationHtml = '<a class="notification-cta" href="'+fullCtaUrl+'" data-notification-id="'+notificationId+'"><div class="media single-notification"><div class="media-left align-self-center"><i class="'+iconClass+' icon-bg-circle bg-yellow bg-darken-3"></i></div><div class="media-body"><h6 class="media-heading yellow darken-3">'+subjectTranslation+'</h6><p class="notification-text font-small-3 text-muted">'+messageTranslation+'</p><small class="float-left"><time class="media-meta text-muted">'+timeSince+'</time></small><small class="float-right"><span class="media-meta cursor-pointer blue text-muted notification-mark-read" data-notification-id="'+notificationId+'">'+res.MarkAsRead+'</span></small></div></div></a>';
        ele.append(notificationHtml);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the AJAX request will complete later than the others, if for exmaple the newest notification is a notification that requires an AJAX request, it will be appended last in the dropdown (rather than first).

All the solutions on SO regarding this all require an AJAX call, in my code, it sometimes uses AJAX, and sometimes not.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I think that you'd simplify your life a whole lot of you'd use a framework like React or Vue, that allows to easily decouple the JS logic from the HTML. Your code looks like a nightmare to debug ^^

Comment: why cant you map all user Ids and send ajax request once and then write logic to handle response, and then execute the non ajax request block

Answer (score 1):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, while appending to the HTML is synchronous, leading to the problem you describe. If you re-structure your code using `async/await` however, you can force your script to finish each action sequentially, whether it's a sync HTML append or an async ajax call.

Your code will look like this:

```js
for (let index=0; index < currentAmountOfUnreadNotifications; index++) {
  const currNotification = response.notifications[index];
  await createAndAppendNotification(notificationHtmlElement, baseUrl, localBaseUrl, currNotification);
}

async function createAndAppendNotification(elt, baseUrl, localBaseUrl, notif) {
  // ...
  if (fromUserId) {
    const resp = await fetch(/* ... */);
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

(If you didn't know about neither fetch nor async/await, time to use them! This ajax call made by jquery is kinda outdated in 2019)

Comment: I'd recommend you to not worry about what works on legacy browser while you *code*, and rather build multiple targets with awesome tools like babel that automatically replace every bit of unsupported code by polyfills